# Sorting numbers using maximum spread

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to sort a list of integers in such a way that they end up being spread out as much as possible. Assuming base 8, the order of items between 1 and 7 ought to be: `{4, 6, 2, 7, 1, 5, 3}` as per:
[image]

There is a fair amount of ambiguity of course, as both 6 and 2 are equally far away from 4, 0 and 8, so the specific ordering of 6 and 2 is irrelevant. What I'm trying to achieve is to first pick the number furthest away from `0` and `base`, then pick the number furthest away from `0`, `base` and `first number`, etc. Any multiple of the base will never occur so I don't care how that is handled.

I can manually design the sort order for any given base, but I need this to work for any `base >= 2`. Is there a clever/fast way to compute this or do I need to lazily build the sorting mapping tables and cache them for future use?

```
int SortOrder(int radix, int value)
{
  int offset = value % radix;     
  int[] table = {int.MinValue, 4, 2, 6, 0, 5, 1, 3}; // Hand-crafted for base-8
  return table[offset];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is specifically not an answer to the question since it doesn't attempt to find the answer quickly. Rather it builds a dictionary of cached sorting values for each radix.

```
#region sorting logic
/// <summary>
/// Maintains a collection of sorting maps for all used number bases.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Dictionary<int, int[]> _sortingTable = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
private static readonly object _sortingLock = new object();

/// <summary>
/// Compute the sorting key for a given multiple.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="radix">Radix or base.</param>
/// <param name="multiple">Multiple.</param>
/// <returns>Sorting key.</returns>
public static int ComputeSortingKey(int radix, long multiple)
{
  if (radix < 2)
    throw new ArgumentException("Radix may not be less than 2.");

  if (multiple == 0)
    return int.MinValue; // multiple=0 always needs to be sorted first, so pick the smallest possible key.

  int[] map;
  if (!_sortingTable.TryGetValue(radix, out map))
    lock (_sortingLock)
    {
      map = new int[radix];
      map[0] = -1; // Multiples of the radix are sorted first.

      int key = 0;
      HashSet<int> occupancy = new HashSet<int> { 0, radix };
      HashSet<int> collection = new HashSet<int>(1.ArrayTo(radix)); // (ArrayTo is an extension method in this project)
      while (collection.Count > 0)
      {
        int maxValue = 0;
        int maxDistance = 0;
        foreach (int value in collection)
        {
          int distance = int.MaxValue;
          foreach (int existingValue in occupancy)
            distance = Math.Min(distance, Math.Abs(existingValue - value));

          if (distance > maxDistance)
          {
            maxDistance = distance;
            maxValue = value;
          }
        }
        collection.Remove(maxValue);
        occupancy.Add(maxValue);
        map[maxValue] = key++;
      }

      _sortingTable.Remove(radix); // Just in case of a race-condition.
      _sortingTable.Add(radix, map);
    }

  long offset = multiple % radix;
  if (offset != 0)
    if (multiple < 0)
      offset = radix - (Math.Abs(multiple) % radix);

  return map[(int)offset];
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score -3):

My original answer was to find the maximum delta. To work your way from out to in, use the same comparison but different selects:

```
 List<double> answer = new List<double>();
        List<double> doub = new List<double>() { 0, -1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 7 };//SORT this list for sorted results!
        List<double> lowerHalf = new List<double>();
        List<double> upperHalf = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < doub.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i <= (int)Math.Floor((double)doub.Count / 2))
                lowerHalf.Add(doub[i]);
            else
                upperHalf.Add(doub[i]);
        }

        if (upperHalf.Count < lowerHalf.Count)
        {
            upperHalf.Insert(0,lowerHalf[lowerHalf.Count-1]);
        }
        //if(upperHalf[0]==lowerHalf[lowerHalf.Count-1]){double median = lowerHalf[lowerHalf.Count-1]+upperHalf[1])/2;lowerHalf[lowerHalf.Count-1] = median; upperHalf[0]=median;}//use Math.Round or Math.Floor/Ceiling if necessary
        for (int i = 0; i < lowerHalf.Count; i++)
        {
            double deltas = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(upperHalf[upperHalf.Count - (i + 1)] - lowerHalf[i], 2));
            answer.Add(deltas);
             Console.WriteLine("The answer for {1}, {2} is: {0}", deltas, lowerHalf[i], upperHalf[upperHalf.Count - (i+1)]);
        }



        Console.ReadLine();
```

This will provide:

The answer for 0, 7 is: 7

The answer for -1, -5 is: 4

The answer for 2, 4 is: 2

The answer for 3, 3 is: 0

**NOTE** that in the event of an odd number of items in the original range, this method uses the same item for both upper and lower lists. I've added a line to use the "actual" median for your benefit

To get rid of duplicates, use a hashset, union, or distinct()

*Original answer - to find maximum delta):*

You can use math in your Linq, like:

```
   List<double> doub = new List<double>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 };
        double deltas =  doub.Select(p => p - doub.First()).OrderBy(p => p).Last();
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is: {0}",deltas);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

If your values go negative, you'd need to use squares:

```
 double deltas = Math.Sqrt( doub.Select(p => Math.Pow(p - doub.First(), 2)).OrderBy(p => p).Last());
```

or Math.Abs or a test to see which is larger - but this should give you an idea on how to get started. If the numbers aren't in order in the original list, you can call an orderby before the select, as well.

Literally:

```
         List<double> doub = new List<double>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 };
        double deltas = Math.Sqrt( doub.Select(p => Math.Pow(p - doub.First(), 2)).OrderBy(p => p).Last());
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is: {0}",deltas);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

produces

```
'OilTracker.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: OilTracker.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OilTracker\OilTracker\bin\Debug\TDAInterface.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'OilTracker.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: OilTracker.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OilTracker\OilTracker\bin\Debug\BackFeeder.exe'. Symbols loaded.
```

**The answer is: 7**

Moving forward to sorting the list, use:

```
 List<double> answer = new List<double>();
        List<double> doub = new List<double>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 };
        //sort doub if necessary
        foreach (double num in doub)
        {
            double deltas = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(doub.Select(p => p - num).OrderBy(p => p).Last(), 2));
            answer.Add(deltas);
            Console.WriteLine("The answer for {1} is: {0}", deltas,num);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

(Again, use another orderby if the list is not in order).

Produces:

```
 'OilTracker.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: OilTracker.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OilTracker\OilTracker\bin\Debug\TDA_Stream_Interface.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 The answer for 0 is: 7
 The answer for 1 is: 6
 The answer for 2 is: 5
 The answer for 3 is: 4
 The answer for 4 is: 3
 The answer for 5 is: 2
 The answer for 7 is: 0
```

The squares/square root help us change signs and deal with negatives - so

```
 List<double> doub = new List<double>() { 0, -1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 7 };
```

Produces:

```
 The answer for 0 is: 7
 The answer for -1 is: 8
 The answer for 2 is: 5
 The answer for 3 is: 4
 The answer for 4 is: 3
 The answer for -5 is: 12
 The answer for 7 is: 0
```

(which aren't in order because I failed to sort the list on either the inbound or outbound sides).

After running, the list "answer" will contain the results - the lowest delta can be accessed by answers.First() and the highest by answers.Last(). similar deltas will exist for different numbers the same number of units apart - you could use a HashSet conversion in the formula if you want to eradicate duplicate deltas. If you need help with that, please let me know.

If you need to store the numbers that created the delta as well as the delta itself, they are available to you in the For/Each loop as the Console.WriteLine() indicates.

If you want to work the range-to-median on both sides of the median, it's probably a good idea to split the list and work in pairs. Make 0 to median in one list, and median to endRange in the second list, work out in the first and in in the second. This should get you there, but if you need help getting over that final hump, let me know.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: what is `p.First()` for a double?

Comment: p.First is the first item in the list to be sorted (in this case, nums). nums.Select (p=>p.First()) will select a list of each item's delta from the first item in the list. You can run it and check b4 you dv - the answer is 7.

Comment: Afraid you're wrong - please see the code I ran and the result in my edited answer.

Comment: No need to be afraid, test your code `List<double> nums = new List<double>(){0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
 double highestDelta = nums.Select(p=> p-p.First()).OrderBy(p=>p).Last();`

Comment: Ahh - brain-compiled code again. Not p.First() - nums.First(). That's what I get for hand-typing. Pretty obviously a typo :/

Comment: There is c# compiler to do this. don't use your brain for it.. BTW I still don't see any code sorting  the array. `Sorting numbers using maximum spread` Do I miss anything ?

Comment: Luckily it is all corrected now and the OP has a viable method for obtaining his/her goals. Thank you, sir, for pointing out my error. I will be certain to take your advice to heart from now on.

Comment: Please feel free to wrap this in a FOR/NEXT and submit it as your own answer.

Comment: feel free to wrap this in a FOR/NEXT and submit it as a complete answer... I don't see how it would help OP

Comment: How this updated answer produces OP's expected result `4, 6, 2, 7, 1, 5, 3`

Comment: I don't see how it helps either. Once 4 is determined as the value furthest away from both 0 and 8, the next value to be picked must take 0, 8 _and_ 4 into account. It's no use precalculating a set of distances for each value in the set. I'm working with ints and longs btw. not doubles. Not sure if that matters for your approach, but at least the Pow and Sqrt invokes stop making sense.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Are you sure you posted this answer to correct question?